# LINEST works with second but not for third order polynomial

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why in the following case the formula LINEST works for second but not for third order polynomial?

This function works: `=LINEST(C2:C19,A2:B19^{1,2},TRUE,TRUE)`

This function fails with #VALUE!: `=LINEST(C2:C19,A2:B19^{1,2,3},TRUE,TRUE)`

Data set:

```
         A       B           C
--+---------------------------------
1 |      X1      X2          Y
2 |     0.60    2.10    0.248063764
3 |     0.60    2.25    0.276777320
4 |     0.60    2.40    0.304976369
5 |     0.60    2.55    0.332532372
6 |     0.60    2.70    0.357305826
7 |     0.60    2.85    0.382830340
8 |     0.60    3.00    0.404655593
9 |     0.75    2.10    0.139118457
10|     0.75    2.25    0.164054336
11|     0.75    2.40    0.189758548
12|     0.75    2.55    0.215962993
13|     0.75    2.70    0.243370030
14|     0.75    2.85    0.267157671
15|     0.75    3.00    0.290327159
16|     0.90    2.10    0.069031327
17|     0.90    2.25    0.083115573
18|     0.90    2.40    0.106105301
19|     0.90    2.55    0.127970351
```

Comment: You need a third column with the coefficientes of the 3rd grade, so you need an `X3` column if you want to do `[1;2;3}`. Something like `=LINEST(D2:D19,A2:C19^{1,2,3},TRUE,TRUE)`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Then why can I produce 2nd (or 3rd) grade for one column of Xs but not 3rd grade for two column of Xs?

Comment: You need to specify a grade for each column, and same backwards (you need a column for each grade specified). If you do `{1;2}` you are specifiying 2 grades, so you just need X1 and X2. If you do `{2;3}` will work too because there are 2 grades and 2 columns. But because you are doing `{1;2;3}` means you need 3 columns

Comment: Jus to clarify, what I said in my previous comment is related to how Excel works when you use notation like `A2:B19^{1,2}` and is not related to the math concepts of linear estimations